# AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE axios invoice

Tags: node.js, axios, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

```js
const headers = {
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${api.oathToken.accessToken}`,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',

}
const body = {
  subject: "No Subject",
  note: "Please pay this within 10 days!",
}
              console.log(invoiceDraft.links[1].href)
                  await axios({
                  data : body, 
                  method: "post",
                  headers: headers,
                  url: invoiceDraft.links[1].href,
                      }).then((response) => {
                        console.log(response.data)
                      }).catch((err)=> {
                        console.log(err.response.data.details)
                        interaction.channel.send(err.toString().slice(0, 1900))
                      })
```

I have this code here to send a created invoice
But for some reason it returns this

Error: Request failed with status code 422

This is a UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY error from Axios and Paypal Invoicing

Im not able to figure out what the issue is.
I am using Node JS and Discord integerations to do this.

```
Error: Request failed with status code 422
    at createError (C:\Users\AriesAsAkshay\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\AspectServices\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (C:\Users\AriesAsAkshay\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\AspectServices\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\AriesAsAkshay\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\AspectServices\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:269:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  config: {
    url: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices/INV2-4PSV-VKBJ-AK8G-P5CL/send',
    method: 'post',
    data: '{"subject":"No Subject","note":"Please pay this within 10 days!","send_to_invoicer":true,"send_to_recipient":true,"additional_recipients":[]}',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: '',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.4',
      'Content-Length': 141
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    }
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: null,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    _closed: false,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'api.sandbox.paypal.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 10,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'api.sandbox.paypal.com',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 933,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    _header: 'POST /v2/invoicing/invoices/INV2-4PSV-VKBJ-AK8G-P5CL/send HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
      'Authorization: \r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/0.21.4\r\n' +
      'Content-Length: 141\r\n' +
      'Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object: null prototype],
      requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
      sockets: [Object: null prototype],
      freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'POST',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    path: '/v2/invoicing/invoices/INV2-4PSV-VKBJ-AK8G-P5CL/send',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      rawTrailers: [],
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 422,
      statusMessage: 'Unprocessable Entity',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: true,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices/INV2-4PSV-VKBJ-AK8G-P5CL/send',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kHeaders)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 18,
      [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
      [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'api.sandbox.paypal.com',
    protocol: 'https:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 141,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices/INV2-4PSV-VKBJ-AK8G-P5CL/send',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'content-type': [Array],
      authorization: [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      'content-length': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    }
  },
  response: {
    status: 422,
    statusText: 'Unprocessable Entity',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'content-length': '377',
      connection: 'close',
      date: 'Wed, 16 Mar 2022 01:35:50 GMT',
      application_id: 'APP-80W284485P519543T',
      'cache-control': 'max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
      caller_acct_num: '7K54CC6QVVV78',
      'paypal-debug-id': 'b5b17b1cdd466',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'
    },
    config: {
      url: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices/INV2-4PSV-VKBJ-AK8G-P5CL/send',
      method: 'post',
      data: '{"subject":"No Subject","note":"Please pay this within 10 days!","send_to_invoicer":true,"send_to_recipient":true,"additional_recipients":[]}',   
      headers: [Object],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      transitional: [Object]
    },
    request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'POST /v2/invoicing/invoices/INV2-4PSV-VKBJ-AK8G-P5CL/send HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
        'Authorization: \r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.21.4\r\n' +
        'Content-Length: 141\r\n' +
        'Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'POST',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/v2/invoicing/invoices/INV2-4PSV-VKBJ-AK8G-P5CL/send',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'api.sandbox.paypal.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    data: {
      name: 'UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY',
      message: 'The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.',
      debug_id: 'b5b17b1cdd466',
      details: [Array],
      links: [Array]
    }
  },
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

Error Response Details

```
[
  {
    issue: 'USER_NOT_FOUND',
    description: 'User is not associated with paypal based on invoicer email.'
  }
]
```

```
           const  sampleInvoice = (
                invoiceNumber,
                fromEmail = "sb-pbqgq14333806@business.example.com",
                toEmail = "sb-47vx64314481641@personal.example.com"
              ) => ({
                detail: {
                  invoice_number: invoiceNumber,
                  currency_code: "USD",
                  payment_term: { term_type: "NET_10" },
                  invoice_date: new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0],
                },
                invoicer: {
                  name: {
                    given_name: "John",
                    surname: "Doe",
                  },
                  email_address: fromEmail,
                  website: "https://www.aspecthosts.com/",
                },
                primary_recipients: [
                  {
                    billing_info: {
                      name: {
                        given_name: "John",
                        surname: "Doe",
                      },
                      email_address: toEmail,
                    },
                  },
                ],
                items: [
                  {
                    name: service,
                    description: "Hello!",
                    quantity: "1",
                    unit_amount: {
                      currency_code: "USD",
                      value: amount,
                    },
                    unit_of_measure: "QUANTITY",
                  },
                ],
              });
```

Comment: Omitting `additional_recipients` returns the same error

Comment: omit send_to_invoicer or set it to false

Comment: Sorry, omitting `send_to_invoicer` ,  `send_to_recipient` , and  `additonial_recipients` still return the same error

Comment: Only other thing in the docs is the `PayPal-Request-Id` header. Not sure if that's relevant though

Comment: Im pretty sure thats Random? IF it isn't, does that go in the `data: `?

Comment: By random i mean, randomly generated

Comment: PayPal-Request-Id is not required, but if specified should be unique as it's used to enforce idempotent requests

Comment: @Fwogo just a quick note about writing comments. Try to collect your thoughts for each one before hitting `Enter`. You don't need to post hundreds of one-line comments. You can also edit them for up to 5 mins if you think of something else to add. You should also go back and delete any that become irrelevant

Comment: Oh ok, sorry Im new to stack overflow. Ty for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there's a problem with the invoice draft's original creation. Show that invoice creation request/response bodies in their entirety. In particular, what is the sandbox email of the invoicer account ? Does it correspond to an actual [www.sandbox.paypal.com](http://www.sandbox.paypal.com) PayPal business account that you can log into? If not, create it with the correct email via [the developer dashboard -> sandbox accounts.](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts)

Comment: Ive editted to show the invoice, the invoice is created into a draft state successfully. But it returns the error i showed when it tries to send the drafted invoice

Comment: Ive also double checked the emails and they are correct

Comment: Im using a personal and buisness email in sandbox

Comment: Also, my invoicer does contain a email_address

Comment: Yeah I see it updated in your question now, before only the create code up top was showing.  What you should do is `console.log(JSON.stringify(sampleInvoice,null,4))` and post that so you have a clear text log of what's actually being sent. That can then be referenced for troubleshooting the issue

Comment: ```console.log(JSON.stringify(sampleInvoice,null,4))``` returns `undefined`

Comment: Do it in the right place? You're the one defining the const :\

Comment: Wdym, do what exactly in the right place? I defined sampleInvoice and then put that line of code.

Comment: Well I don't know what's up with your environment, but it's a straightforward API programming task -- you need to log the plain text of the data you are actually transmitting, not the code you use to set up the object.

Comment: Ive fixed the issue

Comment: Add an answer to this question explaining your solution, then